# Optimizing the performance of joining 3 tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join, query-optimization

I have 3 tables in a MySQL database and I want to write a csv file joining these 3 tables. One is master_table and two others are table1 and table2. Here is my query to join the three tables

```
USE db_test;
SELECT 'feature1', 'feature2', 'feature3', 'feature4', 'feature5', 'feature6', 'feature7', 'feature8'
UNION ALL 
SELECT master_table.feature1, master_table.feature2, master_table.feature3,  master_table.feature4, master_table.feature5, table1.feature6, table1.feature7, table2.feature8 
FROM (master_table RIGHT JOIN table1 
ON master_table.feature1 = table1.feature11) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 
ON table2.feature22 = master_table.feature2
INTO OUTFILE 'datafile.csv'
CHARACTER SET 'utf8'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

This query works fine. I am running it on a server with 64GB RAM and 8 cores.

**PROBLEM**
The master table has around 0.35 million rows. table1 has 0.3 million rows and table 2 has around 100 rows.  It is taking almost an hour to run this query and writing a csv file. I hope there is some way to write a faster query than this. I can not believe the query on this small amount of data is taking an hour on the server.

Comment: Do you have an index on `table1.feature11` ? Can you show the query execution plan?

Comment: A static row with column headers is a weird thing to do. Why not just give the data columns a friendly alias (or leave presentation up to the client altogether)?

Comment: A considerable re-design is what's required. Any time you have columns named x1, x2, x3 etc. you can be sure that your design is less than optimal.

Comment: What is the cardinality of these joins? If you got more than one match for `feature11` and `feature22`, this can create a lot of new rows.

Comment: I am new to SQL . I just tried the above query using my academic experience so I know can weird. I just want few suggestions like indexing in the first comment

Comment: There is only one sensible suggestion: Fix your broken design.

Comment: Those column which had very low cardinality, I normalized them into new tables and table1 and table2 are examples of that. In the master_table I would add 0.35-0.4 million rows weekly but table1 will remain constant.

Comment: Ifyou have academic experience you should not use mysql and should not use right joins.

Answer (score 1):

You are likely missing indexes.  If you could post  SHOW CREATE TABLE master_table,  SHOW INDEX FROM master_table, SHOW INDEX FROM table1,  SHOW INDEX from table2  we could identify missing indexes needed for your posted query.  We would also expeditiously know how many rows are in your tables and the cardinality of the columns that are indexed.
If you could also add in your original question the results of
SHOW GLOBAL STATUS and SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES  some of your peers could review your system volume and check for many issues related to configuration opportunities for improvement.

Answer (score 0):

I worked out the answer and it might be helpful for beginners in databases like me. Also particularly in MySQL.

**ANSWER** The above comments helped me out in studying the core of indexes and I indexed my columns from [this tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_create_index.asp). I index all the columns which I was using as a foreign key (in my case there 2 columns) `feature1` and `feature2`. The result was extremely fast. The query which was taking around `70 minutes` took almost `7 seconds` which is `1000X` faster

Answer (score 0):

Congratulations on using your academic experience plus the community suggestions for places to look.  As a followup, if you could also add in your original question the results of
SHOW GLOBAL STATUS and SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES some of your peers could review your system volume and check for many issues related to configuration opportunities for improvement to reduce the 7 seconds.  Press on, keep learning.